# Why are printf not working properly in Java? JAVA

Tags: java, printf, uiprintformatter

I am getting this type of error in my eclipse software :

**Question**

Why do I get an error?

code :

```
    package loops;
    public class Escapey {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String name ="micheal";
            System.out.printf("i am %s, my friend name also %s",name);
        }
    }
```

Error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s' at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2672) at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1053) at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:949) at loops.Escapey.main(Escapey.java:5)

- Ouput excepted :(

Comment: Just put `, name, name);`...

Comment: because each %s is a parameter, and you have only one parameter

Answer (score 4):

You can either specify the argument twice, or specify an index when referenced in the format string:

```
System.out.printf("i am %1$s, my friend's name also %1$s", name);
```

Comment: @l'L'l is `%0` actually guaranteed behaviour? I can't see it in the documentation: all of the examples start at 1.

Comment: @l'L'l I'm not asking you to demonstrate that it works: I see that it does. That wasn't the point: I'm questioning whether you should rely upon undocumented behaviour.

Comment: @AndyTurner: *No*, undocumented behavior shouldn't be relied upon. It is odd that `javac` doesn't even warn about it though; the `C` compiler does. I'm pretty sure that `Java` simply treats `%0$s` as `%s`, (`%000000$s` is no different).

Comment: "or you could do" don't recommend things you shouldn't rely on without a big warning!

Comment: @AndyTurner: I learned this information through our discussion here. I'm not a compiler — that is where the warning should have come from! I can't edit what I wrote earlier; I've removed it, although the comments that follow don't make much sense, so you might consider removing your comments as well.

Comment: @AndyTurner Hello Andy.....could you suggest me best site to learn java ?? I already learn some basic in java...I dont know where should i learn after java ...

Answer (score 3):

By having two `%s` the `printf` is expecting `two` arguments

like

```
System.out.printf("i am %s, my friend's name also %s",name, name);
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution,

```
System.out.print("i am " + name + ", my friend name also " + name); // If you want to continue on same line 
System.out.println("i am " + name + ", my friend name also " + name); // If you want to continue on next line
```

Since you have two `%s`, two arguments are expected, so either you specify two arguments.

```
System.out.printf("i am %s, my friend name also %s",name, name);
```

Or specify an index in the string. `%1$s` will get the first argument, in this case `name`.

```
System.out.printf("i am %1$s, my friend's name also %1$s", name);
```

**Read more here! :)**

[Java printf( ) Method Quick Reference](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs160/.Summer16/resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf)

[Java Format - Java printf Value Index](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Format/0070__Java_Format_Value_Index.htm) `// explicit indexing, relative indexing`

Comment: System.out.print("i am %s, my friend name also %s",name);
|  Error:
|  no suitable method found for print(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Comment: @Micheal explicit indexing! I have updated my answer with good links you will find very helpful I reckon ( second one especially ).

Comment: wow you are great, It works now :)  Thanks for the link too :) :)

Comment: no problem! consider verifying this answer, so others with the same problem easily finds a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

use this ...

```
System.out.printf("i am %s, my friend name also %s",name, name);
```

You are giving two specifiers. So you need to give name twice here.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty obscure way to do this:

```
System.out.printf("i am %s, my friend's name also %<s", name);
```

I have literally never used this, but it is mentioned in the documentation of [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

> Another way to reference arguments by position is to use the `'<'` (`'\u003c'`) flag, which causes the argument for the previous format specifier to be re-used.

Comment: String name = "sure";
System.out.printf("%s is my name, %<s is okey",name);                                                                         // you are right, < this symbol copying previous arguments,It's really great, Now i am passing a One value name....two %s % in name...Thank you, its cool

Comment: @Micheal Part of making good code is making code easy to understand and IMVHO this obscure way to do this goes against making it easy to understand.